# Can you concatenate statements at run-time in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I am trying to interface with TeamCity using Kotlin-DSL

[In this section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Kotlin+DSL#KotlinDSL-AdvantagesofKotlinDSLvsXML) of the TC Kotlin guide there is a rather odd looking part where it seems like it causes statements to become concatenated on the fly.

It first defines these:

```
val linux = Requirements() {
   contains("os.name", "linux")
}

val oracle = Requirements() {
   equals("db.name", "oracle")
}

val java6 = Requirements() {
   contains("env.JAVA_HOME", "1.6")
}
```

Then does this with those definitions:

```
buildType {
 ...
 requirements(linux + oracle + java6)
 ...
}
```

I know that the above section of code is equivalent to

```
buildType {
 ...
    requirements {
        contains("os.name", "linux")
        equals("db.name", "oracle")
        contains("env.JAVA_HOME", "1.6")
    }
 ...
}
```

So I suppose what my question boils down to is what is the return type of the 'Requirements' function that can just be concatenated together? My guess is it is some sort of statement/ function wrapper and Kotlin lets you concatenate these as you go, and the function signature looks like this:

```
fun Requirements(init: (a: String, b: String) -> UnknownTypeA) : UnknownTypeB
```

---

**EDIT:**
For anyone who is confused when reading this in the future, the calls to Requirements are actually an object initialisation via the Requirements constructor. I do inevitably feel embarrassed for not picking up on this (The casing of the name should have been hint enough!) but I'm making this edit to make it clear to people that it is not a function. Thank you to [Hotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196460/hotkey) for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that `Requirements` accepts a function into its constructor. Without knowing what is the type of that function, let's assume it's `Context.() -> Unit` ([a function with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver) of `Context`, accepting no arguments and [returning `Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions)).

Now, we can naturally [overload the plus operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html) for the `Requirements` type, so that it returns another `Requirements` instance that has a function that applies both functions from the operands.

You could do that in your own code in the following way:

```
class Requirements(val check: Context.() -> Unit)

operator fun Requirements.plus(other: Requirements) = 
    Requirements { check(); other.check() }
```